AutoComplete composable, render on top of the rest of the UI
I am continuing to work on an AutoComplete composable from AutoComplete composable, unable to type while popup is visible:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteExample() {
    Scaffold(topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("AutoCompleteExample") }) }) { innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            val names = listOf("Tony Stark", "Steve Rogers", "Bruce Banner", "Natasha Romanoff")
            var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            val aliases = listOf("Iron Man", "Captain America", "Hulk", "Black Widow")
            var alias by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

            AutoComplete(
                label = { Text("Name") },
                options = names,
                value = name,
                onValueChange = { name = it },
            )
            AutoComplete(
                value = alias,
                options = aliases,
                onValueChange = { alias= it },
                label = { Text("Alias") }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AutoComplete(
    label: @Composable () -> Unit,
    options: List<String>,
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    isError: Boolean = false,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var filteredOpts by remember { mutableStateOf(options) }

    Column {
        TextField(
            label = label,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                onValueChange(it)
                filteredOpts = options.filter { option ->
                    option
                        .lowercase()
                        .contains(it.lowercase())
                }
                expanded = true
            },
            isError = isError,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            modifier = modifier
        )

        if (expanded && filteredOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                filteredOpts.forEach { option ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = option) },
                        onClick = {
                            onValueChange(option)
                            filteredOpts = emptyList()
                            expanded = false
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

So far so good. However, when the user starts typing. The suggestions push the second AutoComplete further down rather than rendering over top of it. How do I fix this?


Maybe you should try using a Popup for the filtered results.
I'v changed your code a bit, its not perfect but look at this:
@Composable
fun AutoComplete(
    label: @Composable () -> Unit,
    options: List<String>,
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    isError: Boolean = false,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var filteredOpts by remember { mutableStateOf(options) }

    Column {
        TextField(
            label = label,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                onValueChange(it)
                filteredOpts = options.filter { option ->
                    option
                        .lowercase()
                        .contains(it.lowercase())
                }
                expanded = true
            },
            isError = isError,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            modifier = modifier
        )

        if (expanded && filteredOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
            Popup(
                alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
                offset = IntOffset(x = 0, y = 200),
                properties = PopupProperties(
                    excludeFromSystemGesture = true,
                ),
                // to dismiss on click outside
                onDismissRequest = {
                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                    expanded = false
                }
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
                ) {
                    filteredOpts.forEach { option ->

                        Box(
                            Modifier
                                .wrapContentHeight()
                                .padding(vertical = 15.dp)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .clickable {
                                    onValueChange(option)
                                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                                    expanded = false
                                },
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(text = option)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


This seems to be in the general direction I want, but it still will take a lot of work to get it to look exactly like I want. To clarify, I'm trying to duplicate AutoCompleteTextView in compose: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView

This is an improved version of Yoav's answer that:

correctly positions the drop down menu
correctly handles the cursor position
sets the completion threshold in case you want the suggestion to start when typing a certain number of characters.

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteExample() {
    Scaffold(topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("AutoCompleteExample") }) }) { innerPadding ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            val names = listOf("Tony Stark", "Steve Rogers", "Bruce Banner", "Natasha Romanoff")
            var name by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

            val aliases = listOf("Iron Man", "Captain America", "Hulk", "Black Widow")
            var alias by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

            AutoCompleteTextField(
                label = { Text("Name") },
                options = names,
                value = name,
                onValueChange = { name = it },
            )
            AutoCompleteTextField(
                value = alias,
                options = aliases,
                onValueChange = { alias = it },
                label = { Text("Alias") }
            )
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteTextField(
    label: @Composable () -> Unit,
    options: List<String>,
    value: TextFieldValue, // I use here TextFieldValue instead of String to be able to control the cursor position
    onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    completionThreshold: Int = 1, // Number of chars that the user must type before completion start
    dropDownBackgroundColor : Color = Color.White,
    dropDownItemHeight : Dp = 48.dp
) {
    var filteredOpts by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>()) }

    // Keep track of text field size to be able to position
    // the popup correctly
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

    Box {
        TextField(
            label = label,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                onValueChange(it)
                filteredOpts = options.filter { option ->
                    it.text.length >= completionThreshold &&
                    option.lowercase().contains(it.text.lowercase())
                }
            },
            isError = isError,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            modifier = modifier.onSizeChanged {
                textFieldSize = it
            }
        )

        if (filteredOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
            Popup(
                offset = IntOffset(x = 0, y = textFieldSize.height),
                onDismissRequest = {
                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                }
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = dropDownBackgroundColor)
                        .shadow(elevation = 2.dp)
                ) {
                    filteredOpts.forEach { option ->

                        // We use here box instead of DropdownMenuItem because
                        // we don't want it to fill the max width like DropdownMenuItem
                        // does. See the source code of DropdownMenuItem for more info
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(
                                    width = with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() },
                                    height = dropDownItemHeight
                                )
                                .clickable {
                                    onValueChange(
                                        TextFieldValue(
                                            text = option,

                                            // put the cursor at the end of the selected text
                                            selection = TextRange(option.length)
                                        )
                                    )
                                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                                },
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                        ) {
                            Text(text = option)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Result:

Edit

I couldn’t reproduce the problem you mentioned. This might happen because of asynchronous delays between typing the text and updating the state. This is a common issue with TextField. I suggest reading this blog post to understand the problem better.
Here are two possible fixes (I’m not sure if they will work, but you can try them):
Option 1
I’ve removed the filtering logic from the onValueChange callback because it might be causing the delay. Instead, the filtering logic now runs in a LaunchedEffect coroutine.
Here’s the updated code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteExample() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text("AutoCompleteExample")
                }
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            val names = listOf("Tony Stark", "Steve Rogers", "Bruce Banner", "Natasha Romanoff")
            var name by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

            val aliases = listOf("Iron Man", "Captain America", "Hulk", "Black Widow")
            var alias by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

            AutoCompleteTextField(
                label = { Text("Name") },
                options = names,
                value = name,
                onValueChange = { name = it },
            )
            AutoCompleteTextField(
                value = alias,
                options = aliases,
                onValueChange = { alias = it },
                label = { Text("Alias") }
            )
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteTextField(
    label: @Composable () -> Unit,
    options: List<String>,
    value: TextFieldValue, // I use here TextFieldValue instead of String to be able to control the cursor position
    onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    isError: Boolean = false,
    completionThreshold: Int = 1, // Number of chars that the user must type before completion start
    dropDownBackgroundColor : Color = Color.White,
    dropDownItemHeight : Dp = 48.dp
) {
    var filteredOpts by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>()) }

    // Keep track of text field size to be able to position
    // the popup correctly
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

    LaunchedEffect(value.text) {
        val text = value.text
        filteredOpts = options.filter { option ->
            text.length >= completionThreshold &&
                    option.lowercase().contains(text.lowercase())
        }
    }

    Box {
        TextField(
            label = label,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = {
                onValueChange(it)
            },
            isError = isError,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            modifier = modifier.onSizeChanged {
                textFieldSize = it
            }
        )

        if (filteredOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
            Popup(
                offset = IntOffset(x = 0, y = textFieldSize.height),
                onDismissRequest = {
                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                }
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = dropDownBackgroundColor)
                        .shadow(elevation = 2.dp)
                ) {
                    filteredOpts.forEach { option ->

                        // We use here box instead of DropdownMenuItem because
                        // we don't want it to fill the max width like DropdownMenuItem
                        // does. See the source code of DropdownMenuItem for more info
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(
                                    width = with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() },
                                    height = dropDownItemHeight
                                )
                                .clickable {
                                    onValueChange(
                                        TextFieldValue(
                                            text = option,

                                            // put the cursor at the end of the selected text
                                            selection = TextRange(option.length)
                                        )
                                    )
                                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                                },
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                        ) {
                            Text(text = option)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Option 2
In this option, I’m using BasicTextField2 (renamed to BasicTextField), which doesn’t have this delay issue. Even though this input doesn’t have the same styling as in the first option, we can add the styling later if it solves the problem.
Here’s the code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteExample() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text("AutoCompleteExample")
                }
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            val names = listOf("Tony Stark", "Steve Rogers", "Bruce Banner", "Natasha Romanoff")
            val state1 = rememberTextFieldState("")

            AutoCompleteTextField(
                state = state1,
                options = names,
            )


            val aliases = listOf("Iron Man", "Captain America", "Hulk", "Black Widow")
            val state2 = rememberTextFieldState("")

            AutoCompleteTextField(
                state = state2,
                options = aliases,
            )
        }
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun AutoCompleteTextField(
    options: List<String>,
    state: TextFieldState = rememberTextFieldState(""), // I use here TextFieldValue instead of String to be able to control the cursor position
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    completionThreshold: Int = 1, // Number of chars that the user must type before completion start
    dropDownBackgroundColor : Color = Color.White,
    dropDownItemHeight : Dp = 48.dp
) {
    var filteredOpts by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>()) }

    // Keep track of text field size to be able to position
    // the popup correctly
    var textFieldSize by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

    LaunchedEffect(state.text) {
        val text = state.text.toString()
        filteredOpts = options.filter { option ->
            text.length >= completionThreshold &&
                    option.lowercase().contains(text.lowercase())
        }
    }

    Box {
        BasicTextField(
            state = state,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            modifier = modifier
                .onSizeChanged {
                    textFieldSize = it
                }
                .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black),
        )

        if (filteredOpts.isNotEmpty()) {
            Popup(
                offset = IntOffset(x = 0, y = textFieldSize.height),
                onDismissRequest = {
                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                }
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = dropDownBackgroundColor)
                        .shadow(elevation = 2.dp)
                ) {
                    filteredOpts.forEach { option ->

                        // We use here box instead of DropdownMenuItem because
                        // we don't want it to fill the max width like DropdownMenuItem
                        // does. See the source code of DropdownMenuItem for more info
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(
                                    width = with(LocalDensity.current) { textFieldSize.width.toDp() },
                                    height = dropDownItemHeight
                                )
                                .clickable {
                                    state.setTextAndPlaceCursorAtEnd(option)
                                    filteredOpts = emptyList()
                                },
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                        ) {
                            Text(text = option)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


What device/emulator image are you running this on? When I try it and start typing, the letters go from right to left. So when I type S then T, I get "ts" in the TextField. I am using an emulator image for Pixel 8 with API 34. I double checked that the language is English, so there shouldn't be any language weirdness going on for me.

I don't encounter the issue you describe! I'm using Pixel 3a API 35 emulator on android studio

I'm coming back to this after several months. I tried it on my phone and I get the same right to left behavior I previously described. What should I look at to troubleshoot this?

@Code-Apprentice i have updated my answer accordingly. Give it a try and let me know if it helps

Thanks for your time and help. I figured it out using ExposedDropDownMenu as in my previous question that I linked at the top of this one. Or rather, I found that what I thought was a problem was a combination of user error and emulator weirdness. I'm moving forward with that solution.
